# Building Project from terminal causes compiler errors

Tags: xcode, swift, build-process

I use Fastlane for automating the build.

If I try use fastlane's gym or Xcode build commands in termainl, some of the swift files are not compiling

The compiler error I get is this:

The following build commands failed:
CompileSwift normal arm64 ***.swift
CompileSwift normal arm64 SOMEFILE.swift
CompileSwift normal arm64 XXX.swift

CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

**When ever I use xcode to archive the build, I do not face any problems.**

**VERSION:** Xcode 6.3.

**MORE LOG**:

xcodebuild[51537:1105705]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-7709/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/SpecificationTypes/BuiltInSpecifications/Compilers/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:77
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/krishnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Business-hcbjqydpndvafhhfzchylvezaqnw/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fastlane-BusinessTest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Business.build/Release-iphoneos/Fastlane-BusinessTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CustomTableViewCell.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CustomTableViewCell.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7f8c2b375f50 {NSFilePath=/Users/krishnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Business-hcbjqydpndvafhhfzchylvezaqnw/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fastlane-BusinessTest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Business.build/Release-iphoneos/Fastlane-BusinessTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CustomTableViewCell.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8c2b31c1e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
NSFilePath = "/Users/krishnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Business-hcbjqydpndvafhhfzchylvezaqnw/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fastlane-BusinessTest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Business.build/Release-iphoneos/Fastlane-BusinessTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CustomTableViewCell.d";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: no. I have not solved it